# Devexpress treelist stateimageindex editing property

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a devexpress treelist control which has some parent and child nodes appended to it.

All parent and child nodes have checkboxes i.e, their state image index is set to 1.

When I open treelist in my app I can't change the state image index and I can't uncheck the check box.

In the image attached those are parent nodes and the check box which has to be edited as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void treeListSuite_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            TreeListHitInfo treeInfo = ((TreeList)sender).CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            TreeListNode oTreeNode = treeInfo.Node;
            if (treeInfo.HitInfoType == HitInfoType.StateImage)
            {
                if (oTreeNode.StateImageIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (oTreeNode.StateImageIndex == 0)
                    {
                        oTreeNode.StateImageIndex = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       oTreeNode.StateImageIndex = 0;
                     }
                } 
          }
       }
```

}